# Struggling to implement a TabControl in iOS App using UIKit Swift and Mongodb

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, uikit, realm

Probably a stupid question but I'm new to Swift and working through some tutorials to learn how this all hangs together.

I've worked through https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/ and got the code working nicely

I'm now trying to add a TabControl to a new welcome page however some of the ViewControllers are failing on "initiliazer".  I think it's something to do with the fact the views that don't work have "init" variables which manage user access via the Realm backend.

Have spent hours Googling and got no-where.  Please can you give me a steer where to start!

The error is occurring at the point I try to set e.g. let tabone = ProjectViewController()

ProjectViewController contains the init which handles whether the user is authenticated in the Realmdb

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of only describing the issue, please also include the code you've attempted, what specific line is not working and what troubleshooting you've done. Take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Keep your code to a minimum to help us understand what you're referring to - as is, it's quite vague.

Comment: Don't put your code in the UIViewController init methods. Put your code in viewDidLoad.